# Visual C++ 2010: Only allow numbers in TextBox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm unfamiliar with Visual Studio, .Net and windows in general, but have been tasked with writing a program that has a windows form. The program pretty much works now, but I have on thing that is bugging me.

I wrote the following function to only allow a number to be input into a `TextBox`:

```
private: System::Void tbPDX_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) {

    if(e->KeyChar == '.'){
        if( this->tbPDX->Text->Contains(".") && !this->tbPDX->SelectedText->Contains(".") )
            e->Handled = true;  
    }
    // Allow negative numbers
    else if(e->KeyChar == '-'){
        if((!System::String::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this->tbPDX->Text)) && !(this->tbPDX->Text->IndexOf('-') == -1))
            e->Handled = true;
    }
    // Accept only digits ".", "-" and the Backspace character
    else if(!Char::IsDigit(e->KeyChar)&& e->KeyChar != 0x08){
        e->Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This works fine for decimal points, but it's not perfect for negatives. For instance I can type `0-.0`. Is there a way of checking that the position of the character being entered is at the beginning of the `String^`? From what I can see it's only possible to see the string before the character was entered?

Comment: So, entering "-" should only be allowed if the string is empty? I'm not sure I see a problem.

Comment: The problem is that if I've already entered say `3.141592635` I'd like to be able to skip back to the beginning of the text box and type `-` to make the input `-3.141592635`, rather than having to delete the entire contents to type `-`.

Comment: So just change the Text property, tbPDX->Text = "-" + tbPDX->Text.

Comment: The correct language tag for this should be C++/CLI

Answer (score 1):

With a little tweak I ended up using the method suggested by Hans Passant.

Here's my final function:

```
private: System::Void tbPDX_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) {

    if(e->KeyChar == '.'){
        if( this->tbPDX->Text->Contains(".") && !this->tbPDX->SelectedText->Contains(".") )
            e->Handled = true;  
    }
    // Allow negative numbers
    else if(e->KeyChar == '-' && !(this->tbPDX->Text->Contains("-"))){
        e->Handled = true;
        tbPDX->Text = "-" + tbPDX->Text;
    }
    // Accept only digits ".", "-" and the Backspace character
    else if(!Char::IsDigit(e->KeyChar)&& e->KeyChar != 0x08){
        e->Handled = true;
    }
}
```